# Sql Server right side restrictions on left join

Tags: sql-server, left-join

Please read it slowly.  This isn't a dup.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST] (

  [TEST_ID]          [integer] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
  ....
  [TEST_TYPE_ID]     [char](1) NULL ,
  ....
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_A] (
  [TEST_ID]          [integer] NOT NULL ,
  ....
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_B] (
  [TEST_ID]          [integer] NOT NULL ,
  ....
)
```

Normally you would write:

```
select  *
from    dbo.TEST as t
left    join dbo.TEST_A as ta on ta.TEST_ID = t.TEST_ID
left    join dbo.TEST_B as tb on tb.TEST_ID = t.TEST_ID
...
```

However, Sql Server can save a lot of work - IF it knows that only some of table TEST's rows potentially join to TEST_A:

```
select  *
from    dbo.TEST as t
left    join dbo.TEST_A as ta on t.TEST_TYPE_ID = 'A'
                                 and ta.TEST_ID = t.TEST_ID
left    join dbo.TEST_B as tb on t.TEST_TYPE_ID = 'B'
                                 and tb.TEST_ID = t.TEST_ID
...
```

These queries return the exact same result. Adding TEST_TYPE_ID = X does not change the result. 
Note: You CAN'T put the restriction on TEST_TYPE_ID in the where statement.  That would change the number of rows returned.

My question is: In a left join if you place a restriction on the right side, will Sql Server use this information first?  Order of operations is very important here.  This is important when TEST and TEST_A are large, but only a few records join.

I have tested this, and the execution plan seems to indicate: no.  It appears Sql Server first does a normal left join trying to join all the records in TEST to TEST_A, then it applies a "filter".  However, I'm not certain I'm reading the execution plan correctly.  If TEST_TYPE_ID = X is applied second, it is effectly a no-op.  If TEST_TYPE_ID = X is applied first, it will limit the left join to only the rows that will actually join.

Note: My actual case looks very different.  I have distilled the question down to this bare bones example to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: First for what? How do you understand what you describe as "restriction"? You need whole "left" table anyway.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to answer this question without a deep understanding of the Sql Server Query Optimizer.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to answer this question without a deep understanding of the Sql Server Query Optimizer.

There are two queries.  They return the exact same result.  The second has a hint in the left join that the query optimizer might use to limit the number of records it attempts to join.  Does the query optimizer use the hint to speed up the join?